# UIModalPresentationFormSheet not showing tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to implement a modal presentation of my settingsViewController. This works fine, but when it is presented it is not showing the tableView which is in the SettingsViewController. It just show a grey background and navigation bar. How come it is not showing my tableView inside the SettingsViewController?

```
    SettingsViewController *settingController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingController];

    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Most likely you have not configured your table view correctly in the interface builder document. Check if `self.tableView` is `nil`.

Comment: did you check the frame(x,y) of your SettingsView ? and Post more code related to your UITableView so that we can see what went wrong.

Comment: the tableview is added through storyboard